# Scala Map as parameters for spark ML models

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I have developed a tool using pyspark. In that tool, the user provides a dict of model parameters, which is then passed to an spark.ml model such as Logistic Regression in the form of LogisticRegression(**params).

Since I am transferring to Scala now, I was wondering how this can be done in Spark using Scala? Coming from Python, my intuition is to pass a Scala Map such as:

```
val params = Map("regParam" -> 100)
val model = new LogisticRegression().set(params)
```

Obviously, it's not as trivial as that. It seem as in scala, we need to set every single parameter separately, like:

```
val model = new LogisticRegression()
         .setRegParam(0.3)
```

I really want to avoid being forced to iterate over all user input parameters and set the appropriate parameters with tons of if clauses.

Any ideas how to solve this as elegantly as in Python?

Answer (score 0):

According to the LogisticRegression [API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression) you need to set each param individually via setter:

> Users can set and get the parameter values through setters and
>   getters, respectively.

An idea is to build your own mapping function to dynamically call the corresponding param setter using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Scala is a statically typed language, hence by-design doesn't have anything like Python's `**params`.  As already being considered, you can store them in a `Map` of type`[K, Any]`, but [type erasure](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20) would erase types of the Map values due to JVM's runtime constraint.

[Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) provides some neat mixed-type features that can circumvent the problem.  An alternative is to use Scala's `TypeTag` to preserve type information, as in the following example:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case class Params[K]( m: Map[(K, TypeTag[_]), Any] ) extends AnyVal {
  def add[V](k: K, v: V)(implicit vt: TypeTag[V]) = this.copy(
      m = this.m + ((k, vt) -> v)
    )
  def grab[V](k: K)(implicit vt: TypeTag[V]) = m((k, vt)).asInstanceOf[V]
}

val params = Params[String](Map.empty).
  add[Int]("a", 100).
  add[String]("b", "xyz").
  add[Double]("c", 5.0).
  add[List[Int]]("d", List(1, 2, 3))
// params: Params[String] = Params( Map(
//   (a,TypeTag[Int]) -> 100, (b,TypeTag[String]) -> xyz, (c,TypeTag[Double]) -> 5.0,
//   (d,TypeTag[scala.List[Int]]) -> List(1, 2, 3)
// ) )

params.grab[Int]("a")
// res1: Int = 100

params.grab[String]("b")
// res2: String = xyz

params.grab[Double]("c")
// res3: Double = 5.0

params.grab[List[Int]]("d")
// res4: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```